# How to insert a currency field in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature

I am tring to create a DocuSign template and I need to be able to insert a field which shows a currency amount (for example $12.55 ). I need to show the dollar sign and possibly calculate the values based on other field values.

I am able to calculate values using a formula fields, but I don't see ho to mask the formula fields to show a dollar sign. The only workaround that I was able to come up with is to make a static text field with a dollar sign next to a formula field as show in the picture:

[image]

Is there a way to add a currency field (validation) in DocuSign?

Answer (score 1):

No - your dollar sign workaround is the only real option, although you do want to make sure you make the $ field read only so the signer doesn't type anything into it.

It would be possible to use custom validation and regex to make a text field that accepts a dollar amount, but it wouldn't be usable with a Formula field. Formula fields only accept input from Number and Date validation fields.

There is an open Enhancement Request regarding this, but it has not been prioritized and is not currently on the roadmap for implementation. If you would like to express interest, contact your DocuSign Account Team and reference issue MAR-29946.

Comment: and for everyone who would like to know the regex formula to validate currency, here it is: ^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$